# I cannot successfully install Nvidia driver and Cuda on my pcc64el Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04, server, nvidia, cuda, ppc64le

I recently installed the Nvidia graphics driver and CUDA on my Ubuntu 15.10 and Ubuntu 16.04 machines (with GTX 970 and GTX 970M respectively), both of which have x86_64 architecture. Much of the installation was done simply with `apt-get`, and the entire process went rather smoothly.

I'm now trying to install the same thing on a POWER8 ppc64el architecture server with Ubuntu 14.04 server edition installed. The server is equipped with Nvidia Tesla M2090 GPU.

However, the "standard" Ubuntu repositories (main, restricted, universe, multiverse) seem to not have Nvidia drivers nor CUDA, I couldn't install with `apt-get` as I did before. I tried downloading the Debian files from Nvidia website for ppc64el-based Ubuntu 14.04 (both graphics driver and CUDA), but the installation didn't quite go through.

Does anyone have experiences installing CUDA on a ppc64el-based Ubuntu server?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I've successfully installed Nvidia drivers and CUDA on a ppc64le system with a Tesla K8, and managed to run some scientific computing applications with CUDA. I needed the drivers from the Nvidia website.

A quick search of the Nvidia drivers from their website give me this: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/95927/en-us which I think will be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I went to the the Nvidia site and was able to download and install the drivers and CUDA (actually in about 30 minutes since I posted the question, but I forgot to come back and retract my question).

You can actually directly download CUDA: [https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). This will install the Nvidia driver for you.

Comment: Hi @Chia-LiKuo! Keep in mind that you don't need to retract your question for situations like this - it's very useful to keep the question up, so that other folks with the same problem can see how to fix it. You can even answer your own questions if you fix it before others have answered. Glad you've got it sorted.

Comment: Right, it makes total sense to keep the question up for others. Thanks @JeremyKerr.

Answer (score -1):

I have filed a bug for this. If you have encountered this issue, please visit the bug report and add your comments, and select the "this bug affects me" option. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1583746